# Conditional distribution involving both discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

We are given that $Y$ is a Gamma$(a,b)$ random variable and $X|Y=y$ is Poisson$(y)$. We are asked to show that $Y|X=x$ is Gamma$(s+x,b+1)$.

So far I have tried to find the joint cdf of $X,Y$, but I failed to do so, and I also doubt that this is the method I ought to use.

I have also tried to treat this problem as a manifestation of the gamma/poisson bayesian model, but that didn't seem to elucidate the problem much for me.

Pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple hierarchical model.  To get the conditional distribution $Y \mid X = x$, we note $$f_{Y \mid X}(y) = \frac{\Pr[X = x \mid Y = y]f_Y(y)}{\Pr[X = x]}.$$  The denominator, the unconditional (marginal) probability mass function of $X$, is not a function of $y$, thus we do not need to compute it to recognize the form of the likelihood in the numerator.  Indeed, we can remove all constants of proportionality with respect to $y$:  we simply have $$\begin{align*} f_{Y \mid X}(y) 
&\propto e^{-y} \frac{y^x}{x!} \cdot \frac{b^a y^{a-1} e^{-by}}{\Gamma(a)} \\
&\propto y^{a+x-1} e^{-(b+1)y}. 
\end{align*}$$
The other factors, $x!$, $b^a$, and $\Gamma(a)$, are not functions of $y$.  What remains is very clearly proportional to a gamma distribution with shape $a+x$ and rate $b+1$; i.e., the conditional density is $$f_{Y \mid X}(y) = \frac{(b+1)^{a+x} y^{a+x-1} e^{-(b+1)y}}{\Gamma(a+x)}.$$

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at your first statement.

Comment: @Ceph it is simply Bayes' theorem.

Comment: I have seen Bayes' theorem only as describing the conditional probability of events. Is it appropriate to interpret $f_Y(y)$ as $Pr(Y=y)$? (If not, how else can one arrive at your statement of Bayes' theorem from the version that has $Pr(A|B)=Pr(B|A)Pr(A)/Pr(B)$)? I thought this was not appropriate, which is why I couldn't understand how to approach the problem.

Comment: If you don't like thinking about that formula as Bayes' theorem, then surely you would agree that the **joint** distribution and conditional distributions are related via the formula $$f_{Y \mid X}(y) \Pr[X = x] = f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \Pr[X = x \mid Y = y]f_Y(y).$$  The fact that $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is continuous only changes my choice of notation, not the underlying concept.

Comment: It is precisely because the final equality in your statement was not obvious to me that I wrote up this question. I know that similar statements are true when $X,Y$ are both discrete, or both continuous. I do not see how to show that this generalizes to a combination of discrete and continuous random variables.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $p$ denote density/mass functions, then we have $p_{Y|X}(y|x)=\frac{p_Y(y)p_{X|Y}(x|y)}{p_X(x)}$. You know all of the RHS terms except for $p_X(x)$, which you can calculate if you're familiar with compound distributions. It turns out $X$ is a negative binomial distribution ([Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution#Examples)), and by eyeballing the mean and variance the parameters should be $r=a$, $p=\frac{b}{1+b}$. Putting this all together and remembering that the binomial coefficient $\left(\begin{array}{c} k+r-1 \\ k\end{array}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(k+r)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(r)}$. After a quick sketch I have a $\frac{b^a}{b^x}$ term that should just be 1 (maybe $p=\frac{1}{1+b}$? That would fix it), but everything else slots into place.

Comment: The computation of $p_X$ is not useful and should be skipped. This is a general theme of the subject.